# Android split action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

my question is certainly stupid, but i really don't understand how to create an split action bar...

I found that on an other topic :

```
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

   String[] tabContent = {"test1", "test2"};
    for (int i=0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
        Tab tab = bar.newTab();
        tab.setText(tabContent[i]);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab);
    }
```

My problem is this split action bar is at the top of my action bar, and not below the action bar.. I don't understand how to change its position.

EDIT : i found the problem but i don't know how to solve it.

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   }
```

If i delete these two lines, it's good, but i want to keep the back button..

DIT 2 :  i want to do the same thing on the second screen : http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-splitaction@2x.png

Answer (score 0):

> i really don't understand how to create an split action bar

There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with a split action bar. You are setting up action bar tabs.

> My problem is this split action bar is at the top of my action bar, and not below the action bar

Action bar tabs will be placed where the action bar wants them to be. Depending upon screen size and orientation, that could be:

- in the action bar itself, as tabs
- in the action bar itself, as a drop-down list
- immediately beneath the action bar

If you want tabs to always appear immediately beneath the action bar, use a different tab solution, such as a `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip`.

Comment: Hello, i edited my topic, i found the problem. Action bar tabs = split action bar, no ? (it is what i understood in the developer documentation Android)

Comment: @Myste: Action bar tabs != split action bar. They have nothing to do with one another, other than they both involve the action bar. A split action bar does not have to have tabs; tabs do not require a split action bar.

Comment: Oh, ok...me i want to do the same thing on the second screen : http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-splitaction@2x.png

Comment: @Myste: The action items at the bottom (plus sign, pencil, trash can) are from the split action bar. The tabs *could* be from the action bar, as for small/normal screens in portrait, action bar tabs will appear as a row beneath the action bar. However, as I noted in my answer, action bar tabs do not *have* to appear that way -- in fact, small/normal screens in portrait is the *only* configuration in which the tabs appear there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand what you mean :/